# Hide powershell.exe from the desktop when its start

Tags: windows-7, powershell

Greeting,
I have this code that will run when windows startup.
The code simply will kill explorer.exe and start remote desktop connection program even a user exit the program it will be restart again.

I have no problem with code but I want to hide powershell.exe from the desktop or minimize it with disabling close button either one will work for me.
I want to do that with powershell program not with remote desktop connection.

Please advice me how to do it.

Regards,

Here is my code:

```
 $i =0
    While ($i -le 1) 
        {
    # get a handle for the Notepad process to wait for
    $rdp = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start( "rdp.rdp" )
    # wait indefinitely...
    $rdp.WaitForExit()
    Start rdp.rdp
    }
```

Comment: wow- I hope security isn't one of your concerns - you might at least monitor this scritp for the inevitable unauthorized modification.

Comment: Security isn't one of my concerns

Comment: do you have an EA license from ms if so they now have a bootable rdp client thats free.

Comment: I have TS licenses Per device (CALs). I have 20 PCs and I want users to use them just to connect to the server. When I turn the PC I just want the user only see remote desktop connection. Note that I have windows 7 home edition so I can not connect these PCs to the domain also no Group Policy option available in  windows 7 home edition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel like I'm helping someone do something crazy here, but to hide the window, you could set this powershell script to run as a scheduled task under the SYSTEM account, or, you could do it with a program, such as in .NET:

```
        procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c " + command);
        procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        **procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;**
        p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
        output = "";
        try
        {
            p.Start();
            output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            p.WaitForExit();
        }..........
```